# GQL test for null IntegerProperty

Tags: null, gql

I'm trying to query records in Google App engine where an IntegerProperty is null (None). This is what I tried without success:

```
data = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE intProp=:1",None)
```

And also with a Query:

```
query = db.Query(MyModel)
query = query.filter('intProp', None) 
data = query.fetch(limit=100)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    intProp = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Do you actually have any instances of `MyModel` with an `intProp` of `None`...?

**Edit**: per the OP's comment it's apparently an issue of schema migration; he added a new property and expected existing entities to have it appear (set to None). That's not how schema changes in GAE work, per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html):

> The App Engine datastore doesn't
>   require all entities to have the same
>   set of properties. After updating your
>   models to add new properties, existing
>   entities will continue to exist
>   without these properties. In some
>   situations, this is fine, and you
>   don't need to do any more work. When
>   would you want to go back and update
>   existing entities so they also have
>   the new properties? One situation
>   would be when you want to do a query
>   based on the new properties. In our
>   example with Pictures, queries like
>   "Most popular" or "Least popular"
>   wouldn't return existing pictures,
>   because they don't (yet) have the
>   ratings properties. To fix this, we'll
>   need to update the existing entities
>   in the datastore.

The essay I'm quoting continues by showing one way to do it, but it's a pretty old-fashioned approach, from before GAE had scheduled tasks, remote apis, &c. We can do it better now. App Engine Fan has a very recent [post](http://blog.appenginefan.com/2009/08/good-bad-and-lucky.html) that shows the general approach (and a mistake he made during his own schema migration, so that others can avoid it!), and points to the [remote API](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) as the key tool; he also points to [a module](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/source/browse/trunk/update_entities.py?spec=svn427&r=427) (from the Rietveld open source core-review project, initiated by Guido van Rossum, author of Python and a key contributor in the development of App Engine) that does the task neatly and properly (you'll need to tweak that code a little so it uses your models &c instead of Rietveld's, of course).

Comment: I've added intProp as a new property to the model. I have instances of MyModel, but intProp contains no data. Maybe new properties are not assigned None?

Comment: Right, when you change the schema the system doesn't intrinsically go over all existing entities, modify them, and save them back; that would potentially be very costly if you had many. You need to manage the schema migration yourself. See http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html .

Answer (score 2):

I managed to query entities with a NULL value using a trick like this:

SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE intProp < 0

Naturally there is no garantie that such a nondocumented method will be compatible with future versions.